# Append HTTP verb

Tags: json, django, rest, tastypie

I have (JSON for) a resource like this at `/api/foo/1/`

`{name: "foo", bar_pks: [10, 11, 12]}`

Now I want to add an API for appending to `bar_pks`. There is no HTTP verb for appending I can find. If I do a patch to `/api/foo/1/` with `{bar_pks: [13]}`, it will overwrite, not append.

1. Is there a verb more consistent with appending?
2. If I modify `patch` for this resource to always do an append, will it come to bite me later?

(I am using Django and Tastypie, but would prefer a language agnostic answer.)

Answer (score 2):

Is there a compelling reason not to do the append on the client side and use a PUT/PATCH to send the updated value back to the server?

I see a couple of options if you're dead-set on doing this:

1. A POST to a new URI which gets interpreted as a an append to the
   list.
2. A query parameter on the PATCH which indicates that the
   changes should be appended rather than overwrite.

Neither of these are good options, and I do not endorse using them.

Comment: I want to avoid using append on client side as it requires two api calls - get to get the list first. (I am a list page, which doesn't have the list of pks.) I will probably go with a post to a different page.